# How can I click the parent menu then redirect to a special URL?

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

You see I have a Navigation bar items, in the parent item `Products & Services` with two sub menus.

[image: redire]

I have a requirement, when I click the menu item `Products & Services` it redirect to its sub-menu `Dedicated Servers`.

How can I do with this?

---

**EDIT-01**

I only want the `Products & Services` parent have this redirect, the other parent do not need, such as `Home`, `Advantage` they all have their own page.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/make-parent-menu-clickable/)

In the wp-admin under menus you just have to replace the ‘#’ with the url for the parent item.

Comment: can you explain more how to do with this? what's the `wp-admin under menus `? and how to `replace the ‘#’ with the url ` ?

Comment: go to the customize page and go for menus and change the url on the "Productd and Services" in the image above

Answer (score 0):

My solution is let the window location redirect redirect to your special URL:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        window.location.href="http://path/to/dedicated-servers/";
    })
</script>
```